# Can you Disable DDMS in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

Does anyone know if it is possible to disable the DDMS in Eclipse? By that I mean DDMS should not being start when Eclipse is launched.

I'd like to use only the DDMS from the terminal, but when I start it it keeps saying:

> Could not open Selected VM debug port
>   (8700). Make sure you do not have
>   another instance
>       of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by
>   something else, choose a
>       new port number in the preferences.

I like the standalone DDMS better than the one that is built in to Eclipse, mostly because it is far easier to switch between DDMS and the source code that way. And, I feel it's being put too much into the same program when DDMS is run as a plugin to Eclipse. Also, as DDMS is quite unstable and crashes a lot, its easier to restart only DDMS and not having to restart the "not-so-fast" Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ADT plugin depends on the DDMS plugin. 
Even if you (Help > About Eclipse SDK > Installation Details) uninstall the DDMS plugin it will still try to connect to the device.So, You can remove both or none of them.

First In First Served. The first DDMS instance will get the connection and the other will still continue complaining.

Comment: Thanks. Not what I was hoping for, but we'll just have to accept the current situation.. Hopefully later revisions of DDMS will address this.

Answer (score 7):

You have to start DDMS before you start Eclipse.
Also, set the debugger port to something like 32767 in Eclipse.
Go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS and set Base local debugger port to 32767.

Comment: Didn't help. Now I'm getting the same error message when I start Eclipse instead.

Comment: Do you get the error message even after Eclipse has finished loading?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error message. Eclipse has finished loading. I'm on a mac if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm on Linux, and doing what I described only makes Eclipse complain once on startup that it can't open the port. After that it's all good.

Comment: I see what you mean. That's what happens to me too. However, my question was if I could disable DDMS in Eclipse so that it will not be launched when I launch Eclipse. Does anyone know how this can be done? Or isn't it possible once you've got the android plugin installed?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to disable it. On a side note, if you set up a shortcut for "Next Perspective" (e.g. Ctrl-Tab), switching between DDMS and Java would be a lot quicker.

Comment: Uninstalling DDMS on Eclipse and changing the port number helped. Ubuntu. By the way, running standalone DDMS is depricated. `/tools/monitor` is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Try these settings in your Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Android->DDMS section:

[image: 1 Millisecond DDMS connection timeout setting]

Comment: Disable DDMS in Eclipse... Basically giving it the wrong port so it won't try to connect before his external one does.

Answer (score 0):

For me was the problem that I need to have the ddms running in a IDE instance that is started from the first eclipse IDE. But as ddms is already started be the 1. ide, I got the same port problem. I found that you must rename the ddms.bat file in your Android SDK installation in the folder "tools" (e.g. C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools) so Eclipse IDE cannot start ddms. Before you start a second instance of eclipse, you rename it back.