# Eclipse and Android Studio open at the same time?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Funny question, I know. But for Android development purposes, I need to have Eclipse AND Android Studio active at the same time, on a mac. The problem is that "both" AVD managers detects a running emulator and it all screws up.

Do you have any tips on "disabling" the AVD on Eclipse, beside removing the ADT bundle all together?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406391/can-you-disable-ddms-in-eclipse) seems to be related, also without solution.

Comment: The only thing that I know of is disabling the ADB integration on Android Studio. To do so, disable `Tools --> Android --> Enable ADB integration`. Not really sure that is what you want tough.

Comment: How about you don't even start the AVD on Eclipse?

Comment: How do I achieve that @ojonugwaochalifu ?

Comment: @user3956566 if I'm debugging on AS and I open Eclipse, I get a message "Could not open selected VM debug port 8700. Make sure you don't have another instance of DDMS or the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences".
Unfortunately I cannot find such preference?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but try to change the port number. http://www42.zippyshare.com/v/XZzx3wvR/file.html

Comment: thanks @ZsoltBoldizsár, tried that but it isn't the same -- I still get complaints about port 8700 ..

Comment: thanks @dextor , do you know a way to disable ADB in Eclipse?

Comment: @ticofab Not that I know of. I believe if you install ADT then you're sticking with ADB integration.